# How to set system fonts in a HTML select control?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select control in my project. I want to use this control to system fonts. How can I do it?
I searched but don't find any thing about HTML select.

```
 <select id="Select1">
       <option></option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Completely blank!!!..Post youre code or eleborate a bit more..

Comment: What does "bind html select to system fonts" mean? You want to use some font in a select element? Then the question should be "How to use different font in a html select?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change font-family of drop down's list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696004/how-to-change-font-family-of-drop-downs-list-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to target the select with CSS to change the font. In your CSS:

```
select {
    font-family: your-font-choice, your-second-choice, your-third-choice;
}
```

The caveat being that the only font change the will be visible is the default/selected option. When you click the dropdown button, the menu that shows all your options will have a font set by the browser, which you can't change for the most part. The alternative is to use a javascript built custom select input that will allow you to style everything.

Answer (score 1):

**[See the Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8LDDj/2/)**

```
select {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

**[Another Demo with custom google font](http://jsfiddle.net/8LDDj/1/)**

Comment: I want to set my system fonts in a html select, how do I it?