# select options font-family is not working in mac os(chrome and safari browser issue) and window safari browser issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to apply the font family different to each option. it is working with chorme and mozila. but in safari it gives default font only. can you please suggest how to do this.

```
<select>
    <option value="'Proxima Nova Alt Light'" style="font-family: 'Proxima Nova Alt Light'">Proxima Nova</option>
    <option value="Arial" style="font-family: Arial">Arial</option>
    <option value="Helvetica" style="font-family: Helvetica">Helvetica</option>
    <option value="Verdana" style="font-family: Verdana">Verdana</option>
    <option value="Courier" style="font-family: Courier" >Courier</option>
    <option value="CraftyGirlsRegular" style="font-family: CraftyGirlsRegular" >Crafty Girls Regular</option>
    <option value="MarckScriptRegular" style="font-family: MarckScriptRegular" >Marck Script Regular</option>
</select>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change font-family of drop down's list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696004/how-to-change-font-family-of-drop-downs-list-item)

Comment: That's different. I already told that it is working in chrome and firefox ... I have issue with safari

Comment: It's not different, read the answer again. You can't style select element in Safari, for me it does not work in Chrome too.

Comment: it is not work in chrome only for mac os.. for windows chrome it will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the font-family of select options for safari browser.

You can use custom plugin to do this.

[Reference link](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-optgroup-option-css-safari/)

Comment: @HD.. You're welcome. If you think the answer is helpful, you can upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: yeah sure.. Answer is helpful..I will give you upvote..,.