# I want to change font-family of option tag but it's not working. is it possible without javascript if yes then please explain

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this dropdown list:

[image]

And the code for it is given below:

```
<select name="pro_cat_id[]" id="pro_cat_id[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    <option value="-1">Select</option>

                    <option style="font-family:Shivaji01; font-size:20px;" value="1">Police Station 1</option>
                    <option style="font-family:Shivaji01; font-size:20px;" value="2">Police Station 2</option>


                                </select>
```

I've written the code but it's not working. Also using internal and external CSS but not working.

Link CSS when inline remove:

```
    select > option{
    font-family:Shivaji01;
    color:red;
   font-size:20px;
   }
```

I tried both ways but not working so please anyone have solution for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font-family of drop down's list item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696004/how-to-change-font-family-of-drop-downs-list-item)

Comment: Its not a good idea to style the select element as some browsers do not support the ability to style them. I would recommend using a JS library such as [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/).

Comment: shall you give any idea how to do it with jquery?

Comment: You can't style select dropdown, the only way is to create widget that replace the select with custom element or use existing widget like the one from jQuery UI.

Comment: will you please give me any link of that type of jquery widget?

Answer (score -1):

The font you are using doesn't seems to be a standard font, that does mean that the font won't be available on end users machine. So you will have to embed the font before you use it in your CSS.

To embed the font through CSS follow this steps.
 1. First download the font's ('Shivaji01') .eot and .ttf version.
 2. Add the font to your application by creating a "fonts" directory in the same directory as your your stylesheet and place the .eot and .ttf files in the fonts directory.
 3. In your stylesheet embed the font as below.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Shivaji';
    src: url('fonts/Shivaji01.eot'), url('fonts/Shivaji01.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal; //
    font-style: normal;
}
```

4. Use the embed font in your CSS.

> ```
> select > option{
>         font-family:'Shivaji';
>         color:red;
>        font-size:20px;
>        }
> ```

5. Remove the inline styles you have given to the "option" tag.

This should work now.

You can read more about font embedding from Google or start with the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp