# Optgroup breaks special characters

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari, font-awesome

I need to a add an icon from Fontawesome to an option of a selector. It works fine, unless I use optgroup

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="group name">
        <option>opt1 &#xf042;</option>
        <option>opt2 &#xf043;</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option>opt3 &#xf042;</option>
    <option>opt4 &#xf043;</option>
</select>
```

Here's [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpfzk0LL/).

Any ideas why?

Comment: I get a _rect_ sign either way ... Chrome 58/Windows 10

Comment: But in Firefox it works as is :)

Comment: For me it works in IE 11, Chrome 58. Breaks in FF 53. All on Windows 7.

Comment: My IE11/Windows 10 doesn't work ... I guess the form elements _again_ has difficulties to adapt to more modern techniques :)

Comment: I had a similar problem, but related to CSS classes. <i class="fa-flag"> worked on Chrome, but only <i class="fa fa-flag"> worked on Firefox. Try adding a class="fa" to the element

Answer (score 3):

I updated your fiddle to use external resources.

It imports a javascript file and a css file, and the icons show now.

If you make an account on FontAwesome they will send you a link.
Try the below in your code and see if it works, I'm betting it will.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/cec949909c.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle doesn't work on Windows 8.1 (latest FF + IE11), looks like there is something with the select from the OS. Even without optgroup it still does not work, so optgroupt has nothing to do with it.

Looks like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696004/how-to-change-font-family-of-drop-downs-list-item) is still valid. Workaround: use jQuery plugins instead.